Can a Svelte component dipsatch its own instance?
For nested Svlete components, where an Outer contains several Inners, is it possible to create a dispatcher with createEventDispatcher in Inner that would communicate the instance that called the dispatcher?
Outer.svelte would look something like
<script lang="ts">
  import Inner from "./Inner.svelte";

  /* placeholder array of 0-10 elements, to make it clear the number of Inners
   * in this component is different depedning on some outside factors */
  let dynamicContent = Array.from({length: Math.random() * 10}, () => "something");

  // How is it possible to set this?
  let lastSelectedInner: Inner | null = null;
</script>

{#each dynamicContent as item}
  <Inner on:select={(event) => lastSelectedInner = event.detail} />
{/each}

And Inner.svelte would look something like:
<script lang="ts>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
</script>

<button on:click={() => dispatch("select", /* how do I forward the instance here? */)} >
  <p>Click me</p>
</button>

Note: I need the actual instance to be in a variable, and not an index. Also, I don't want to have an array of all Inners, just a single reference to a single component.

Why does the parent component need a reference to the child component instance? Often, it's enough to pass data to the child component instance using props, and if the parent needs the child to change in some way, one simply changes the props one pass to it.

In my use case, there are quite many props and functions from the child that need to be available in the Outer component, and the Outer can have hundreds of Inners, so it's inefficient to store arrays/indices. I also need don't like the idea of storing an "index" prop in Inner, as that's illogical encapsulation-wise: Inner doens't need to know it's one of many, and it shouldn't matter if it's part of an array or not: it logically has no "index", that's part of the parent's structure.

After several solutions with good workarounds were proposed, I was looking into futher options that would fully satisfy the requirement of "no array of inners" and "communicate actual component reference".
I have come across a Svelte REPL (not sure who the author is) that shows how to make this possible using the special <svelte:self> element. Here is the solution outlined there, adapted to this question. Inner.svelte:
<script lang="ts">
  export let outer = true;
  export let component = null;

  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
</script>

{#if outer}
  <svelte:self 
    bind:this={component}
    outer={false}
    on:select={() => dispatch("select", component)}
  />
{/if}

{#if !outer}
  <button on:click={() => dispatch("select")} >
    <p>Click me</p>
  </button>
{/if}

This approach isn't the most readable, as it requires nesting the inner component within itself and conditionally showing content only in the nested component. However, it achieves precisely the result of being able to dispatch an event from a component, that in its detail communicates a single correctly-typed reference.
Edit: Updated according to comment from @Corrl

Do you have a working Repl using this approach?

I think it needs to be adjusted to make it work https://svelte.dev/repl/908de9703eb4472f8e744d3ca0a7f331?version=4.2.18

@Corrl Good point, thank you for pointing it out. I wrote it very quick and didn't actually test yet. Indeed it's needed to forward the inner-inner component's event in the outer-inner component (sorry for confusing names, the variables in the REPL were named the same as the components in my question).

From your comment, it sounds like the parent component instance doesn't actually need to access the child component instance, only (some of) the data in the child component instance. So the child component instance can pass along that data in the event, and not the component instance itself. And maybe passing along data is not needed at all?
Outher.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import Inner from "./Inner.svelte";
  
  
  let items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: `a`,
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: `b`,
  }]

  let selectedItem: Object | null = null; // I don't know TS, so unsure about type ^^'

</script>

{#each items as item}
  <Inner on:select={(event) => selectedItem = item} />
{/each}

{#if selectedItem}
  <h1>Selected</h1>
  <div>Id: {selectedItem.id}</div>
  <div>Name: {selectedItem.name}</div>
{/if}


Thank you, but this doesn't fit the criteria described in the question. I need an actual reference to the actual child component. The example code in the question is very simple, just for demonstrating the minimal setup needed and the end goal. The actual use case is much more complex and likely unnecessary for me to explain, but one thing is clear: a parent component needs a reference to one of its dynamically generated child components. That's what the question is about, and this answer entirely omits that.

Unless you'd like to edit or update the answer so it fits the criteria, could I ask you to delete this please? Since it doesn't answer the question, I'd rather it be clear the question is unanswered.

As far as I know (but I'm not sure), a component instance can't get a reference to itself (unless you work around that by using the parent in a way you don't want to). So the short answer to your question is probably Not possible. Then suggesting workarounds are good answers IMO. And you might not be looking for the particular workaround I have suggested, but others in the future who think they have the same problem as you and find this question might find this workaround a good solution for them. But if you disagree, feel free to downvote, that's what the button is for.

I wouldn't want to downvote as you put effort into suggesting an answer, and it just feels rude to do, but maybe it's good to start off the answer with something like: the short answer "this is not possible due to Svelte not allowing ..., but a possible workaround is ...", instead of "you probably don't need this", as the need itself is up to the question to determine, and the suggested solution is a workaround with several downsides.

As far as I know the child component can't access a reference to itself but it would have to be created via bind:this in the parent and passed as a prop.
This would be a way to set lastSelectedInner without adding additional logic to the Inner component
<script>
  import Inner from "./Inner.svelte";

  /* placeholder array of 0-10 elements, to make it clear the number of Inners
   * in this component is different depedning on some outside factors */
  let dynamicContent = Array.from({length: Math.random() * 10}, () => "something");

    let innerRefs = []
    
  // How is it possible to set this?
  let lastSelectedInner = null;
    $: console.log(lastSelectedInner)   
</script>

{#each dynamicContent as item, index}
  <Inner bind:this={innerRefs[index]}
        on:select={() => lastSelectedInner = innerRefs[index]} />
{/each}


Thank you, I was aware of this approach but would very much like to avoid storing all the references, as there are possilby quite many. Maybe I'm conditioned by lower level languages for such optimization and it matters less in-browser, but somehow a thousand-element array being necessary for a situation where only one item is actually relevant rubs me the wrong way. Is there somewhere in the Svelte docs that I could find reasons why a component can't reference itself?
